# How do I stop blender from crashing upon rendering?

Tags: rendering

whenever i render this animation in eevee in 2.8, but it insta crashes. i have the .blend file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hA-R5YJlBemjBjLV8KPZPjMCKW9yBbQ/view?usp=sharing
can anyone help me?

Comment: Does it crash for every animation or just that one?

Comment: What's the tile size set to? Also, is it rendering on GPU or CPU?

Comment: i'm using evee render engine. it says that in the post.